# How to clear terminal after SSH login?

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I am trying to connect to a server via ssh. Once connected, terminal should be cleared.

Due to generated keys, I can connect to the server via `ssh usr@svr` without being prompted a password. This works.

In order to get rid off

> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free
>   software; the exact distribution terms for each program are described
>   in the individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
>   permitted by applicable law.

I would usually just type `clear`. However, I would prefer not to type this every time but automate the procedure instead.

`ssh usr@svr "clear"` --> "TERM environment variable not set.". I googled several solutions about unset environment variables, but without success.

So instead, I tried `ssh -t usr@vr "clear"`; this successfully clears the terminal, but also closes the connection right away ("Connection to IP closed."). Computer connects to server, clears the screen, closes the connection.

Next attempt was to create a bash script on the server to be run after connecting to it.

```
#/bin/bash
clear
## cl.sh, chmod +x
```

`ssh usr@svr ./cl.sh` --> "TERM environment variable not set.".

Another attempt was to create a bash script connecting to the server and clearing the terminal via `ENDSSH`.

```
#/bin/bash
ssh usr@svr <<'ENDSSH'
clear
ENDSSH
## sc.sh, chmod +x
```

Running this results in:

```
> ./sc.sh
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7-v7+ #755 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:20:48 GMT 2015 armv7l
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
TERM environment variable not set.
```

I am a beginner at this, so please be patient if I have made a very obvious mistake. I tried to be as detailed as possible and researched this before posting, but could not find an answer to my question. For example, commands other than "clear" work (`ssh usr@svr ls`), but that does not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found another easy solution

```
ssh -t usr@svr 'clear;bash'
```

Answer (score 1):

The text your question refers to is part of the message-of-the-day (MOTD).

If you can become root on the server, you can just modify that message in `/etc/motd`. Note that depending on the server's distribution, this file will usually be generated somehow (overwriting any changes), e.g. on Debian it is generated from `/etc/motd.tail` at boot, so you might have to change that file instead.

See manpage `motd(5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The above mentioned solution with .hushlogin seemed easier though.

Comment: You are welcome. I agree with you, and it also meets the "user" perspective better.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent that message from being printed you can create a file named `.hushlogin` in your home directory (on the server). SSH to the server and run the command `touch ~/.hushlogin`. If that file exists then the login shell will no longer print the motd (message of the day) which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

All startup messages are defined in `motd` file (`/etc/motd`).

However if you'd like to having your console cleared to increase privacy, add the following code:

```
 [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
```

Either to your `.bash_profile` or `.bash_logout` (on logout). Or by using `clear` command.

Clearing screen on logout is the default behaviour on Debian Linux distribution.